# get the <DIV> tag from webbrowser control

Tags: c#, windows

my situation is like this.. i used a webbrowser control to present a web content in my application.. now i want to modify a div tag(its content width,height & etc.).. so does anyone know how to grab the div from its id.... if it cant be done with webbrowser control please be kind enough to tell me the a possible method...

Comment: I've merged your unregistered account into your registered one. You can now edit your question, accept an answer and leave comments under individual answers for clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Call `webBrowser.Document.GetElementByID("...")`.